# Getting [Object Object] when doing getItemAt() in List

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, dataprovider

I have set my data provider as `Bindable` as such:

```
        [Bindable]
        public var dataProvider:ArrayCollection;

        public function init():void{

            dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(
                [{label:"x"},
                    {label:"y"},
                    {label:"z"}]);
```

Then in a function called upon CLick event of a button, I want to get the item at a particular index

```
private function getmyItem(event:Event):void {
                trace(dataProvider.length);
                trace(dataProvider.getItemAt(1));
                                 //OR
trace(dataProvider.getItemAt(myList.selectedIndex));
}
```

But I am getting `[Object Object]` in my trace. Can someone tell me what is the prob with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not any obvious what do you want to get in `trace` but I can guess the following fixes can solve your problem:

```
private function getmyItem(event:Event):void {
                trace(dataProvider.length);
                trace(dataProvider.getItemAt(1).label);
                                 //OR
trace(dataProvider.getItemAt(myList.selectedIndex).label);
}
```

Comment: Oopss..I always miss to specify the object name :(

Thx again Constantiner

Comment: However I am having an issue. Since the list consists of TextInput as itemrenderer, if for example at index 1 of the list, I modify the Text in the textInput from "abc" to "abcd", when trying to trace it back..I still get "abc"

I believe something specific needs to be done done in the TextInputRenderer?

Answer (score 2):

your code is not complete

```
trace(dataProvider.getItemAt(myList.selectedIndex).label);
trace("your_tilelist_name".dataProvider.getItemAt(myList.selectedIndex).label);

private function getmyItem(event:Event):void {
            trace("your_tilelist_name".dataProvider.length);
            trace("your_tilelist_name".dataProvider.getItemAt(1).label);
                            //OR
trace("your_tilelist_name".dataProvider.getItemAt(myList.selectedIndex).label);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{label:"x"},
{label:"y"},
{label:"z"}
```

These are `Objects` created using `{}` syntax.

```
var obj:Object = {some:"value"};
trace(obj); // [object Object]
```